# Atributos dos produtos não funcionando na hora da venda - WooCommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Tenho produtos variáveis e simples na loja. Porém, os produtos variáveis, mesmo com estoque, preço e estando habilitados com as mesmas configurações de um produto simples, ele não permite a venda. Ainda não consegui resolver o problema.

[image: Atributo do produto com estoque]

[image: Não permite a compra]

Comment: faltam mais detalhes, por exemplo, que código é executado no click no botão Comprar?

Comment: É o padrão do WooCommerce

Comment: Criei a loja normalmente, adicionei os atributos e ativei o plugin  
WooCommerce Variation Swatches da ThemeAlien

Comment: Não ta faltando colocar o preço da variação ali?

Comment: kkkkkk obrigado